# why is the ping on localhost so high when i use websockets?

Tags: c++, node.js, websocket, cocos2d-x, libwebsockets

I am using a simple node.js server to broadcast messages:

```
var ws = require('websocket.io');
var server = ws.listen(3000);
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('message', function(data) {
                server.clients.forEach(function(client) {
                        client.send(data);
                });
        });
});
```

The client is written in c++ (cocos2dx framework) and it's working like this:

```
_websocket = new WebSocket();
_websocket->init(*this, "ws://localhost:3000");
....
_websocket->send(message);
```

When I measure the latency by sending something to the server and waiting for the response: it's around **80-100ms**. The node.js server runs on localhost and I would expect the ping to be around 0-10ms max. 
Do you know the reason why the ping is so high? Do I have to flush something or is something wrong with the server setup?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used the framework that you are using but I have used the `CometD` implementation in Java. There were a lot of parameters for things like buffering, message packing etc... that had a large effect on the system performance. I suggest that you post your config. Also don't overly invest in optimising a `ping`... that is hardly going to be close to your real use case.

Comment: apperently this is something cocos2dx or websockets related. i did the same test but with an java server implementation of websockets with the same result. node.js is not the problem. if anyone knows what configs i need to change in order to make the ping go under 10ms, please let me know :)

Comment: Do you have front end web server like Apache in your stack?